# route add application net traffic

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion

Recently I´ve been changed from a building in my job and I have a small issue. Do you know how can I route a traffic to a specified gateway but only when SSH y used?

I have in my macmini 2 network interfaces, the lan and the wifi.
 - Lan IP Addres: 10.0.70.16 gateway 10.0.0.101 ( Local network)
 - Wifi IP Addres: 192.168.1.188 gateway 192.168.1.1 (Internet access)

Everything works fine but I have a server with a 192.168.1.1 (diferent network) and it is accesible throught LAN network using route add 192.168.1.1 10.0.0.101 command. But If I do that, I lost my Internet access.

I need to route my traffic only when accessing to 192.168.1.1 using SSH. Any clue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you have two hosts with the ip address

```
192.168.1.1
```

The route change you made disconnects you because the Default Gateway for your Wifi is 192.168.1.1.  So your mac will try to route all traffic leaving your mac via wifi to that host.  You are telling the mac to route to that via the wired interface instead.  I suspect that whatever is on the wired Lan with 192.168.1.1 is not operating as a router so it is not forwarding your traffic on and thus your traffic is being dropped.

If you are using the ssh client that comes with OSX, it supports the BindAddress option (see the man page for ssh_config) which you could try using to bind to your wired lan port and try to ssh to the 192.168.1.1 ip like this:

```
ssh -o BindAddress=10.0.70.16 192.168.1.1
```

This should send ssh traffic to your lan gateway 10.0.0.101 destined for 192.168.1.1 which it should forward on to the network that the 192.168.1.1 you are trying to reach is on.

Comment: Yes, I have two 192.168.1.1 host, one is my wifi gateway and the other is a debian server witch I can reach throught my LAN network (my IP is 10.0.70.16). I tried with this command but I get "ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.1 port 22: Operation timed out". The perfect solution will be to say to ssh that it has to connect always with my LAN adapter and not with my Wifi adapter. But only when it is ssh.

Comment: Essentially the BindAddress directive to ssh does tell it which adapter to connect with since it has to use the adaptor with the specified ip assigned.  But if you mean across ip address changes on that interface (e.g. for new dhcp assignments) you want it to automatically bind to whatever ip is on a named interface, there don't seem to be arguments to ssh to do that.  If 10.0.0.101 was a linux router You could try setting a ProxyCommand which would ssh to 10.0.0.101 and run nc to bounce your traffic on to the 192.168.1.1 you want, maybe: ProxyCommand ssh 10.0.0.101 nc 192.168.1.1:22

Answer (score 1):

By default the SSH deamon binds to every available interface.

If you wish to bind ssh to 1 IP address, let's say 192.168.1.10, this can be done by changing the sshd_config file to include:

```
ListenAddress 192.168.1.1
```

Restart sshd daemon.

Depending on your firewall software, you need to configure some sort of server-to-client port forwarding rule to forward only those requests that goes to your specified machine 192.168.1.1 on the specific port (22 in this case).

Hope this helps.